# JNI error in function jni_createJavaJVM

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm having some issues with instantiating the JVM. If I run the code below standalone, it works fine. However, I need to integrate it into a bigger tool that will call a java library.

The program initially invokes the createVM method and then the invokePrismWrapper method. However, method JNI_CreateJavaVM(...) returns JNI_ERR.

**Preprocessor**

```
#define USER_CLASSPATH ".:../ ....
```

**CreateVM function**

```
JNIEnv* createVM (JavaVM **jvm)
{
  JNIEnv *env;                       /* pointer to native method interface */
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;            /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
  JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1]; //holds various JVM optional settings
  options[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>("-Djava.class.path="USER_CLASSPATH);
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;         //version of Java platform 
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;     
  vm_args.options = options;    
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;   
  /* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface * pointer in env */
  long status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

  if (status == JNI_ERR){
    cout << "\n Unable to load JVM \n Exit";
    exit(-1);
  }

  delete options;
  return env;
}
```

**invokePrismWrapper method**

```
float invokePrismWrapper(JavaVM **jvm, JNIEnv *env){
  jclass    mainClass       = env->FindClass(MainClass);    //Returns a class object from a fully-qualified name, or NULL if the class cannot be found.
  jmethodID classConstructor    = env->GetMethodID(mainClass, "<init>", "()V"); //Returns the method ID for an instance (nonstatic) method of a class 
  jobject   classObject     = env->NewObject(mainClass, classConstructor); //Constructs a new java object

  float outcome = 0;

  if (mainClass!=0){
   jmethodID methodid = env->GetMethodID(mainClass, "goPrism", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
   if (methodid!=0){
        jstring result = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(classObject, methodid); //returns the result of the calling method, an object 
        const jbyte *str = (jbyte *)(env)->GetStringUTFChars(result, NULL);  // Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding
        outcome = ::atof((char*)str);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(result, (char*)str);
        cout << "Result: " << outcome << endl;
   }
   else{
       cout << "Method not found!" << endl;
   }
    return outcome;
  }
  else{
    cout << "Class Not found" << endl;
    return -1;  
  }
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)

FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server")

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-ljvm")

# add the binary tree directory to the search path for include files
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ADD_LIBRARY(PRISMLibrary SHARED JNIWrapper.cpp)

message("JNI:- " ${JNI_LIBRARIES})
message("Source Dir: - " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (PRISMLibrary ${JNI_LIBRARIES})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is different about the larger program that makes this fail?

Comment: The `createVM` function declares it returns a pointer to `JNIEnv` but there's no return statement. Are you actually running this code or did you redact it?

Comment: I forgot to copy/paste the return statement. I've also updated the topic with the CMake script that I wrote to compile the code. @ErnestFriedman-Hill: The problem is that when I invoke the createVM function from the larger software, it halts. When I use it as a standalone application, it executes fine.

Comment: Are both exes 32 bit (or 64 bit)?

Comment: @doctorlove: 64 bits. I can run both (the larger software and the binding class that creates the JVM and invokes the java class) as standalone applications. But, I cannot run the binding class from the large software

Comment: Again, I ask: there must be something about the larger software that is different from a small app with just the binding class. Does the larger software include multiple threads? A GUI toolkit like Qt? Signal handling? What are the characteristics of the larger software that might interfere with the loading of the JVM?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Sorry for not understanding your question. The larger software indeed uses multiple threads to exchange messages. The  larger software has a topology similar to star, where there is a central node that manages the communication between the leaves. Each leaf is an application and you can create a larger application by combining leaves, depending on the requirements. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Make sure the per-thread stack size is set large enough; it may be smaller under pthreads (say) then without. And I have no real evidence for this, but I have a belief that creating the VM from any thread other than the main application thread may cause problems.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Thanks for your reply. Is there any source that gives an idea how to do this? I'll try it and let you know the result.